# HP laptop battery malfunctioning after insatlling ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, power-management, laptop, battery

I installed ubuntu 20.04 replacing my previous os windows 10. I use an HP notebook Da0077tx laptop(lithium-ion battery =). It didn't have any battery issue in windows 10, but after installing ubuntu it malfunctions like it will get stuck at some point and won't charge, the label shows charging but it doesn't, once removed from charging it will drain in like a couple of minutes. I reinstalled ubuntu 20.04  today hoping to get rid of this problem, but it's still not working properly. I used this command to check the power status:

```
upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
```

Here's the output:

```
tery_BAT0
  native-path:          (null)
  power supply:         no
  updated:              Thursday 01 January 1970 05:30:00 AM (1598906856 seconds ago)
  has history:          no
  has statistics:       no
  unknown
    warning-level:       unknown
    battery-level:       unknown
    icon-name:          '(null)'
```

It's been more than one week of a search now and still haven't figured out what's the problem. I am pretty sure it's not a hardware problem.

These are some relevant images from Power statistics:
[image]
[image]

I was using the wrong command for upower, the correct command and output are:

```
upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT1
```

output:

```
 native-path:          BAT1
  vendor:               Hewlett-Packard
  model:                PABAS0241231
  serial:               41167
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Wednesday 02 September 2020 08:46:12 PM (76 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               charging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              6.5094 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         23.1876 Wh
    energy-full-design:  41.04 Wh
    energy-rate:         0 W
    voltage:             12.064 V
    percentage:          28%
    capacity:            56.5%
    technology:          lithium-ion
    icon-name:          'battery-low-charging-symbolic'
  History (charge):
    1599059772  28.000  charging
```

I still have no clue why is it happening, I am eagarly waiting for some positive respone.
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: So I figured out that I was using the wrong command for upower, the correct one is : upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT1. Still, I don't understand what's the issue

Answer (score 0):

The reason why is your battery has lost half its capacity and is going bad. Your battery is at this capacity you should replace it     capacity:            56.5% use these things for more battery powertop tlp and pop os graphics switcher https://support.system76.com/articles/graphics-switch-ubuntu/ you also need to install nvidia drivers

Comment: you also likely had power optimizations which helped your battery if you need to get tlp and powertop to help also.